# Multiple dex files in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, virtual-machine, android-gradle-plugin

HI i found this error and for last two days i am playing with error but did not run the project. please any one help me. i delete the android support v4.jar from main project not delete from libraries project because they have their own dependencies and also delete the anotation jar. annotation jar, android support v4, and appcompact v4 is using in External Libraries project. but still i found this issue. this is my jar list

```
android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar
AndroidAnimations.jar
AndroidEasingFunctions-1.0.0.jar
google-http-client-1.16.0-rc.jar
google-play-services.jar
gson-2.1.jar
```

And this is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iptikarpromotion"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar')
    compile files('libs/AndroidAnimations.jar')
    compile files('libs/AndroidEasingFunctions-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.16.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.1.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:ImageSliderLibrary')
    compile project(':libraries:GalleryViewLibrary')
}
```

please see this belopw error

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class android/support/annotation/AnimRes is included twice in your project, maybe in two different libraries. You need to find it out what is and exclude one of them.